# Normalización del tamaño de las imágenes

Tags: html, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Tengo una galería de imágenes creada con Bootstrap 4.6. Cada componente de la galería tiene una tamaño el cual se adapta con la clase `img-fluid` de Bootstrap, pero no conozco el termino y tampoco conozco o sé si es posible que cada elemento tenga un tamaño normalizado pero su modal pueda abrir la imagen con las dimensiones que tenga original mente, desconozco cómo se le llama a esto y si con HTML o Bootstrap es posible.

Les dejo un trozo del código de la galería por si alguien necesita dar un ejemplo:

```html
<!-- ficheros de bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- codigo de usuario -->
<div class="container-fluid mb-5 gallery">
  <div class="row  m-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="1700">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active carousel-caption " data-interval="1700">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block bg-bodycarousel">
              <h5>Titulo Contenido 1</h5>
              <p>Un texto que puede describir un contenido especifico</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item " data-interval="1700">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block bg-bodycarousel">
              <h5>Titulo Contenido 2</h5>
              <p>Un texto que puede describir un contenido especifico</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="1700">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block bg-bodycarousel">
              <h5>Titulo Contenido 3</h5>
              <p>Un texto que puede describir un contenido especifico</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 mt-4 ">
      <a href="#!" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalimage1">
        <img loading="lazy" class="img-fluid  m-2 gallery-item zoom2 item-caption " src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" onContextMenu="return false;" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 mt-4">
      <a href="#!" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalimage2">
        <img loading="lazy" class="img-fluid m-2 gallery-item zoom2 item-caption" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" oncontextmenu="return false;" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 mt-4">
      <a href="#!" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalimage3">
        <img loading="lazy" class="img-fluid m-2 gallery-item zoom2 item-caption" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 mt-4">
      <a href="#!" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalimage4">
        <img loading="lazy" class="img-fluid m-2 gallery-item zoom2 item-caption" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 ">
      <a href="#!" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalimage5">
        <img loading="lazy" class="img-fluid m-2 gallery-item zoom2 item-caption" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x250" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 ">
      <a href="#!" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalimage6">
        <img loading="lazy" class="img-fluid m-2 gallery-item zoom2 item-caption" src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x450" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 ">
      <a href="#!" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalimage7">
        <img loading="lazy" class="img-fluid m-2 gallery-item zoom2 item-caption" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 ">
      <a href="#!" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalimage8">
        <img loading="lazy" class="img-fluid m-2 gallery-item zoom2 item-caption" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 mt-4">
      <a href="#!" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalimage1">
        <img loading="lazy" class="img-fluid  m-2 gallery-item zoom2 item-caption" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 mt-4">
      <a href="#!" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalimage2">
        <img loading="lazy" class="img-fluid m-2 gallery-item zoom2 item-caption" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 mt-4">
      <a href="#!" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalimage3">
        <img loading="lazy" class="img-fluid m-2 gallery-item zoom2 item-caption" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 mt-4">
      <a href="#!" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalimage4">
        <img loading="lazy" class="img-fluid m-2 gallery-item zoom2 item-caption" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 ">
      <a href="#!" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalimage9">
        <img loading="lazy" class="img-fluid m-2 gallery-item zoom2 item-caption" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 ">
      <a href="#!" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalimage10">
        <img loading="lazy" class="img-fluid m-2 gallery-item zoom2 item-caption" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 ">
      <a href="#!" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalimage12">
        <img loading="lazy" class="img-fluid m-2 gallery-item zoom2 item-caption" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x250" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 ">
      <a href="#!" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalimage13">
        <img loading="lazy" class="img-fluid m-2 gallery-item zoom2 item-caption" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="gallery-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      <img loading="lazy" class="img-fluid  m-2   modal-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pongo esto como comentario, porque no sé si Bootstrap lo tiene, pero podrías hacerlo con HTML/CSS: pon un tamaño de imagen similar para todas las imágenes y luego con CSS dales `object-fit: cover;` (funciona más o menos como `background-size: cover` y la imagen se adaptará a su contenedor cortándose algunas partes que quedarán no visibles). Luego al abrir el modal, muestras la imagen tal cual.

Comment: Gracias Alvaro por mejorar mi pregunta y voy a tratar de probar ese método que me acabas de mencionar gracias , si llego a conseguir algo vuelvo a comentar

Comment: Intente probar object-fit pero nada alvaro no estaria logrando el resultado que busco gracias por la sugerencia

Comment: Deja que pruebe y te digo. Creo que object-fit funcionaría pero es CSS, no Bootstrap.

Comment: Hola @Batvizz, he puesto el código como ejecutable (cambiando las imágenes para que se carguen bien)... pero parece no funcionar. ¿Podrías ponerlo tal y como lo tienes para que se vea el problema mejor? ¿El carrusel hace falta? (Parece que es código innecesario para la pregunta en sí) ¿Cuándo/cómo se abre el modal? He probado pulsando en las imágenes de la galería pero no ocurre nada. Parece que falta algo de JavaScript para que la demo funcione correctamente.

Comment: hola alvaro , tendria que subir un repositorio a github con los archivos para que puedas ver el codigo o armarte un ejemplo minimo , esta tarde lo edito tambien me voy a fijar ese codigo que me mencionas , gracias